# SDL_ttf display glitches

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm trying to display the string "hey" using a true type font in SDL, but there are glitches. Here is the text as it should appear (I took a screen recording, so the lower part in this shot is just the control for the video player):

[image: "hey" without glitch]

And here it is with a glitch:

[image: "hey" with glitch]

As you can see the upper part of the letter "h" is missing.

Here is the code that I used:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int fatal( std::string m ) {
    std::cout << "Fatal error: " << m << "\n";
    exit(-1);   
}

void drawText(TTF_Font* font,SDL_Renderer* r, std::string message) {
    SDL_Color c = {255,255,255,255};
    SDL_Surface *temp = TTF_RenderText_Blended( font, message.c_str(), c);
    if ( temp == NULL )
        fatal("failed to create surface");
    SDL_Texture *txt = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( r, temp );
    if ( txt == NULL )
        fatal("failed to create texture");
    SDL_FreeSurface( temp );
    SDL_Rect src;
    src.x = 0;
    src.y = 0;
    SDL_QueryTexture( txt, NULL, NULL, &src.w, &src.h );
    SDL_Rect pos;
    pos.x = 80;
    pos.y = 80;
    pos.w = src.w;
    pos.h = src.h;
    if ( SDL_RenderCopy(r,txt,&src,&pos) != 0)
        fatal("SDL_RenderCopy failed");
    SDL_DestroyTexture(txt);    
}

extern "C" int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) != 0 )
        fatal("sdl_init failed");
    if ( TTF_Init() != 0 )
        fatal("ttf_init failed");
    if ( SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer ( 200, 200, 0, &window, &renderer ) != 0 )
        fatal("sdl_createwindowandrenderer failed");
    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont( "Arial.ttf", 30 ); 
    if ( font == NULL ) 
        fatal("failed to open font");
    SDL_Event e;
    while ( 1 ) {
        if ( SDL_PollEvent(&e) ) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                break;
        }
        // clear back buffer
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0,0,255,255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);  
        drawText(font,renderer,"hey");
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Which I compiled on macOS 10.15.6 using the following command

```
g++ -std=c++17 textTest.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf
```

Comment: Well for anyone else who has the same issue, it made a big difference to initialise SDL by initialising the window and renderer separately using SDL_CreateWindow and SDL_CreateRenderer and setting the flags for the renderer to SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC. However, for more complex loops than the above, the issue is still there to some extent. It doesn't occur if I compile into webassembly using empscripten (which requires putting the loop in a separate function). So there's something about the environment which is causing this issue.

Comment: Additional comment: it helps a lot if the texture for the text is not repeatedly created every loop. So instead a table of text for each visible ascii character is created in advance, and then text is drawn using that. It's unclear why this was an issue on the macOS enviroment described, but it definitely put less pressure on ram. It leads to noticeable speed improvements in low-end devices (e.g. a cheap phone/tablet) too.